# Cakephp - Finding records with no associated records

Tags: cakephp, inner-join

Ok, so I have this:

```
$user_id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$joins = [
        ['table' => 'subscriptions',
            'alias' => 'Subscription',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => [
                'Subscription.thread_id = Thread.id',
                'Subscription.user_id = '.$user_id
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $unsubscribed = $this->Thread->find('all',[
        'contain' => [
            'Subscription' => ['conditions' => ['Subscription.user_id' => $user_id]]
        ],
        'joins' => $joins,
        'fields' => ['name','modified'],
        'limit' => 10
    ]);

    debug($unsubscribed);
```

It basically finds all threads with a subscription attached to the current user.
What I really want though, is the negative result. Or in other words: all the threads that do not have a subscription by the current user? 
Is there a way to make the conditions negative? Or something like that?

Comment: what about `'Subscription.user_id != '.$user_id` in `$joins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your relations are:

- Thread hasMany Subscription
- Subscription belongsTo Thread

Your SQL would be:

```
SELECT Thread.*
FROM threads AS Thread
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS Subscription
  ON Thread.id = Subscription.thread_id
    AND Subscription.user_id = ##user_id##
WHERE Subscription.user_id IS NULL;
```

The key concept is that you need a LEFT JOIN, not an INNER JOIN. This SQL joins all threads to all of the user's subscriptions AND does not eliminate those thread rows which do not have a subscription (i.e., the purpose of the LEFT JOIN). Then only select records that don't have a subscription (as found in the WHERE clause)

Translating to Cakephp:

```
$user_id = AuthComponent::user('id');
$joins = [
    ['table' => 'subscriptions',
        'alias' => 'Subscription',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => [
            'Subscription.thread_id = Thread.id',
            'Subscription.user_id = '.$user_id
        ]
    ]
];

$unsubscribed = $this->Thread->find('all',[
    'conditions' => ['Subscription.user_id' => null],
    'joins' => $joins,
    'fields' => ['name','modified'],
    'limit' => 10
]);

debug($unsubscribed);
```

Comment: Sounds right, but I can't make it work. I suppose you meant the condition to be: 
'conditions' => ['Subscription.user_id =!' => $user_id],

But that doesn't work either. It just returns an empty array. And I did check that valid results exist.

Comment: `'conditions' => ['Subscription.user_id' => null]` should generate `WHERE Subscription.user_id IS NULL`